# quartz scheduler to run on specific day and time, run every hour and should continue from there

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

Is it possible to fire a job which will

1. start on a specific date and time
2. run every hour from 1:00
3. from there it should continue till next 3 months **for all days**

EX:

1. Start the job on Feb 12 2017, 1:00 AM, runs every hour i.e 2:00AM, 3:00AM
2. and continue till April 12 2017 **for days**

Assuming my current date is 10 Nov 2016

Any solution for unix cron is also fine

Below will schedule only on 12th of Feb, Mar and April 2017.

`|------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Seconds | Minutes | Hours | DayOfMonth | Month | DayOfWeek | Year|
|         |         |       |            |       |           |     |
|   0     |    0    | */1   |   12       |   2-4 |     ?     | 2017|
|------------------------------------------------------------------|`

Answer (score 0):

It can achieved using **3 cron jobs programatically**.

**First job**:- to register the second cron job on the day it should start. Will be triggered(run) only once.
**Second job**:- to run every hour. Will be triggered multiple times
**Third job**:- to de-register the second cron job . Will be triggered only once.

**Explanantion:-**

- when the program starts, schedule the first job and also the third job on appropriate dates respectively.
- When the first job is ready to run, it will schedule the second job.
- When the third job is ready to run, it will remove the second job.